# Создать функцию-обработчик в классе

Tags: php, классы

Не могу понять, почему не работает данный подход

```
class MyClass {
    private $ErrorHandler = null;

    // Зарегистрировать обработчик ошибок
    public function RegisterErrorHandler($ErrorHandlerFn) {
        $this->ErrorHandler = $ErrorHandlerFn;
    }

    // Симуляция ошибки
    public function TestError(){
        if($this->ErrorHandler) { // Если определен обработчик ошибок
            $this->ErrorHandler('Текст ошибки');
        }
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();

$myClass->RegisterErrorHandler(function($errorText){
    echo $errorText;
});

$myClass->TestError();
```

В то время, как данный код совершенно исправно работает

```
$ErrorHandler = function($errorText){
    echo $errorText;
};

$ErrorHandler('Текст ошибки');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае php пытается вызвать неопределенную функцию `MyClass::ErrorHandler`
Для обхода можно использовать `call_user_func`

```
public function TestError(){
    if(is_callable($this->ErrorHandler)) { // Если определен обработчик ошибок
        call_user_func($this->ErrorHandler,'Текст ошибки');
    }
}
```

[Тест](http://ideone.com/OlKa0e)